# MySQL ERROR 1064 (42000) - even with backticks

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I must be missing something obvious, but still...

I get MySQL ERROR 1064 (42000) when I try to run the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `mgr_user`
(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `customer_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(25),
    `password` VARCHAR(100),

    INDEX(`customer_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY `customer_id` REFERENCES `customer`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON     DELETE RESTRICT
 );
```

Comment: this is the only other create:

Comment: CREATE TABLE customer
(
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR(25),
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

Comment: Please show the error message, which often helpfully reveals where the syntax error is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **wrap around the foreign key name with parenthesis**. Also your **auto column must be a key**. See bellow

```
CREATE TABLE `mgr_user`
(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `customer_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(25),
    `password` VARCHAR(100),
    INDEX(`customer_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`id`),  --  <- Auto column is should be a key
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
 );
```

After these 2 changes, I got `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)`